# WPF Xaml GridView SelectionChanged Behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am working with a WPF view with Prism.MVVM which allows our users to edit records.
Originally the record to be edited was selected via ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Records}"                 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}"/>
```

This worked, but users wanted a more efficient way of finding which records had fields which needed updating so we have added a read only DataGrid which they can sort and visually spot which records they are interested in. Next they want to select the record to edit off the grid (but keep the combo box). This is where things go wrong.

Ideally the behavior we are looking for is:

- If user selects a record from combo box:

  1. The selected record is loaded in the form
  2. The selected record is shown as selected in the combo box.
  3. The selected record is shown as selected in the grid.
- If user selects a record in Grid

  4. single click to select record.
  5. The selected record is loaded in the form
  6. The selected record is shown as selected in the combo box
  7. The selected record is shown as selected in the grid.

### Most Successful Attempt

**Trigger Command on SelectionChanged event of DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridRecords}}"
          SelectedItem="DataContext.SelectedRecord, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=OneWay}">
...
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TheDataGrid}"
                               Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectRecordFromGridCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

DelegateCommand:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property SelectRecordFromGridCommand As DelegateCommand(Of TheRecordType) = new DelegateCommand(Of TheRecordType)(Sub(r) SelectedRecord = r)
```

This was attempted with various options for the `SelectedItem` binding mode.
If the DataGrid `SelectedItem` binding is removed, We get 1,2,4,5,6, and 7. but selecting the record from the combo box would not show the record as selected in the grid.

If the DataGrid `SelectedItem` binding is set to `OneWay`, Selecting a record via the combo box breaks: Setting `SelectedRecord` triggers the SelectionChanged event in the DataGrid, which uses the value before the event and effectively sets everything back to the original value.

**This can be remedied by introducing a sentinal on the Set of the Property in the ViewModel**

```vb
Private _selectedRecord As TheRecordType
Private _enableRecordSelection As Boolean = true
Public Property SelectedRecord As TheRecordType
    Get
        Return _selectedRecord 
    End Get
    Set(value As TheRecordType)
        If _enableRecordSelection 
            _enableRecordSelection = false
            SetProperty(_selectedRecord , value)
            _enableRecordSelection = true
        End If            
    End Set
End Property
```

This actually works, and we came up with it while writing the question, but feels horribly hacky. My gut is telling me there has to be a better way so I'm still asking:

*Is there a clean (preferably xaml only) way to set this up?*

### The other *most successful* things we tried:

**Straight xaml configuration for the DataGrid with TwoWay binding**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TheDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GridRecords}}"
          SelectedItem="DataContext.SelectedRecord, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

With this, we satisfy requirements 1 through 6; however when selecting the record through the grid, the previous record is always highlighted instead of the current one.

**DataGrid.InputBindings**

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TheDataGrid}"
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectRecordFromGridCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

With no `SelectedItem` binding, this behaves similarly to the no binding `InteractionTrigger` on `SelectionChanged`, except it requires the user to perform multiple mouse actions. A first click selects the row in the grid (actual bold blue selection) The second click triggers the Command.

With a `OneWay` binding on `SelectedItem`, this behaves similarly to the straight xaml config, again except needing to click multiple times.

Again to reiterate the question:
Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the 7 requirements than to resort to the sentinal value on the property setter?

Answer (score 0):

According to you ask, I understand that you want to **sync the selected item in Datagrid and ComboBox**. If I were you, I will use the that two control binding the same object(**SelectedRecord**). I only familiar with C#, so the code is write in C#. Hope it can help you.

**For XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Records}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRecord}" />
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Records}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Id"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRecord}" />
```

**For ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Record> Records { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Record>();

public Record SelectedRecord
{
    get { return _selectedRecord; }
    set
    {
        _selectedRecord = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
public class Record
{
    private static int id = 0;
    public Record()
    {
        Id = ++id;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing SelectedValue to my attention, however this is behaving identically to the section **Straight xaml configuration for the DataGrid with TwoWay binding** in my question. When selecting the record from the grid, the row shown as selected always lags one click behind. If Z is initially selected, and I click on Y, Z still shows as selected in the grid, everywhere else on the page is updated to Y. If I then click on X, Y shows as selected in the grid & everywhere else on the page is updated to X.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor, I think the two way binding shouldn't the reason to cause the selected delay problem. Whether you use other trigger or command affect it? In my test, I cann't reproduce your problem.